# Calling/instantiating function explicitly with 'templatized template'

Tags: c++, templates

Following code works fine:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrap {};

template<template <class> class OUT, typename IN>
void Extract (OUT<IN> *obj)
{ /* only class 'IN' is used in some way */ }

int main ()
{
  Wrap<int> obj;
  Extract(&obj);
}
```

But, I am passing a pointer argument to extract the outer type and inner type.

Is there any better way by which I can invoke the method with explicit template instantiation ? 
`Extract<Wrap<int> > ()`;

### Edit:

I will detail my question a bit more. This explains, why the easy answer like  `Extract<Wrap, int>();` is not possible.
I am writing a text parser, for C++ code. Wherever, parser finds,

```
x = (Type) y;
```

it should convert into,

```
x = Extract<Type> (y);
```

Now, the Type can be

1. any normal type like, `int*` or `A**`
2. some templatized template like `Wrap<A>`

Now, `Extract()` works different for both the cases. I have to figure out using template that, whether it's `Extract<int*>` or `Extract<Wrap<int> >`.

==> In simpler language, the method can be called:

1. `Extract<int*>()`
2. `Extract<Wrap<int> >()`

I can figure out if it's called in 1st case, but how can I figure out if it's called in 2nd case ? (provided that, I want to know internal type also).

Comment: Can you actually give us an example that demonstrates the problem you're having rather than an orthogonal problem then? I can't quite grasp what you're really trying to do from your edited description.

Comment: @Mark B, I have edited the last section. Have tried my best to explain. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `Extract<Wrap, int> (&obj);`?

But why do you want to specify it explicitly? Most of the time you'd rather have the compiler deduce the types for you automatically for simplicity.

EDIT: Have you considered just specializing for `Wrap<U>`?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Wrap {};

template <class T>
struct Foo
{
static void Extract()
{
    std::cout << "Base type" << std::endl;
    // Stuff
}
};

template <class U>
struct Foo<Wrap<U> >
{
static void Extract()
{
    std::cout << "Extract<Wrap<U> >" << std::endl;
    // Stuff for Wrap
}
};

int main ()
{
  Foo<int>::Extract();
  Foo<Wrap<int> >::Extract ();
}
```

If needed you can add a specialization for `T*` as well.

Comment: I think it's partially right. Because, I need to make specialization for all the wrapper classes such as 'Wrap1', 'Wrap2'. Even, I had thought of enclosing the function inside a struct and do something like, `Foo<Type1>::Extract<Type2>()`. But wanted to know, if we can do simply without using enclosing class.

Comment: @iammilind You can't partially specialized a function based on the `Wrap<T>` which is why I had to create the wrapper class to contain it.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrap {};

template<template <class> class OUT, typename IN>
void Extract ()
{
    IN x; // IN => int
} 

int main ()
{
  Wrap<int> obj;
  Extract<Wrap, int>();
}
```

You certainly lack basic understanding of C++ templates. Read the book [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842).

Comment: Why do you feel I "lack basic understanding of C++ templates" ?

Comment: @iammilind : That's because you were tring to pass `Wrap<int>` as the template argument where you should have written `Wrap`. No offense meant BTW. Your question is much more clear now.